# How can I express this element?

Tags: javascript, arrays, chart.js

Hello I have this code using javascript and chart.js :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>

<div id = "Global">
<div id = "gauche">
<canvas id="line-chart" width="800" height="450"></canvas>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("line-chart").getContext('2d'); 
var config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            data: [{'y': 426777.148122,'x': 18.123},
{'y': 258927.721326,'x': 46.8603108462},
{'y': 5419.37148146,'x': 1110.14081215},
{'y': 5136.33830766,'x': 1138.878123}],
            label: "Model",
            borderColor: "#3e95cd",
            fill: false     
        }, {
            label : 'Data',
            fill:false,
            showLine: false,
            backgroundColor: "#FF0000",
            data : [{x: 17.0, y: 454995.091169},
{x: 1137.0, y: 3369.7047454},
{x: 1138.0, y: 3539.605825},
{x: 1140.0, y: 4927.1313084}],
                        type: 'line'
        }]        
    },
    options: {
        title:{
            display: true,
            text:"Graph"
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'logarithmic',
                position: 'bottom'
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                type: 'logarithmic'
            }]
        }
    }
};
var forecast_chart = new Chart(ctx, config);

alert(data.datasets[0].data);

</script>
```

But when I type this : `alert(data.datasets[0].data);` I get nothing... basically I just want to express this `426777.148122` which is part of the data but I don't know how to do it, I thought to write this `data.datasets[0].data` but it does not work...

Any ideas ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Try: alert(config.data.datasets[0].data[0].X) or Y to get indivisual value, or simply use JSON.stringify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:
alert(JSON.stringify(**config**.data.datasets[0].data[0]));

You will need JSON.stringify because **config**.data.datasets[0].data is also an array of objects

or

alert(**config**.data.datasets[0].data[0].x);

To get the X value of the first entry of **config**.data.datasets[0].data